# Compiler Error: "expected specifier-qualifier-list"

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct a
    {
        static int w;
        char *p;
    } a;
}
```

on compiling it gives  `error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'static'`
could u please tell me what this error means and how to remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local classes cannot have static data members in C++.

To quote the standard (Paragraph 9.8.4)

> A local class shall not have static data members.

In the unlikely case that you don't know, a local class is a class, struct, or union defined in function scope.

9.8.1

> A class can be defined within a function definition; such a class is
>   called a local class.

Comment: @Shashi Bhushan: C does not support static data members.

Comment: @Shashi: I have removed the C tag from your question because your declaration of `main()` is not C.

Comment: @Armen thanx, missed return statement i guess...well i have to look more on static data member in C..

Comment: @Armen What about a global structure, there also it throws the same error.

Comment: @Armen: Sorry, was trying it in C, missed the C++ tag in the question.

Answer (score -1):

`static` is a storage class, so it does not properly apply to a `typedef`.  It's along the same lines as `register` and `const`.

Even if `static` worked, how would `w` be static and `p` not be static?

This will work though:

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct a
    {
        int w;
        char *p;
    } a;
    static a a0;
}
```